# Parcel - добавления свг спрайта к проекту

Tags: svg, спрайт

Коллеги, пробую парсел как альтернативный вебпаку сборщик проектов и он мне нравится, но есть два НО, которые пока не удаётся победить ( вот ссылки на стартовые сборки - [сборка на парселе](https://github.com/Nikolasgrizli/Starter-parcel)
и [сборка на вебпаке](https://github.com/Nikolasgrizli/Starter-webpack5-/tree/onelang) ):

**1)**  В сборке под вебпаком использовал для создания свг спрайтов svg-sprite-loader который добавляет сразу после открытия боди свг с символами вот такой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в сборке для парсела такого плагина нет, пробовал поставить parcel-plugin-svg-sprite но он не собирает отдельно спрайт( по крайней мере я не нашёл такого решения в документации ).
По итогу пока вставляю свг таким образом как описано в документации парсела (использую мопса в проекте):

```
svg
   use(href="../../icons/facebook.svg")
```

но и в этом случае получаю лишь пустое место((

**2)** При сборке проекта получается одна папка с массой файлов, что не совсем удобно, в документации нашёл что можно с помощью флага -d задать название для папки в которой собираешь проект, но не нашёл как можно разбить отдельно html/css/js/imgs по папкам.

Заранее благодарен за любую помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Разработчик плагина для первого парсела сделал сборку для второго парсела, и я говорю спасибо ему! Вот плагин, протестировал его с html и pug, всё работает!  https://github.com/Epimodev/parcel-plugin-svg-sprite